# How can I display more points (GeoPoint) on a map?

Tags: dictionary, point

Currently I am able to display one point the first point that I crated in the code(pointStatie), but I want to be displayed both points.
I want to be displayed the point where I am located and another point that I passed the coordinates from another class.

My current code is:

```
package aexp.elistcbox;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Address;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.io.*;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class GPSLocatorActivity extends MapActivity 
{
    public MapView mapView;
    public MapController mapController;
    public LocationManager locationManager;
    public LocationListener locationListener;
    public String best;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

    mapView.setSatellite(false);

    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(13); 

      locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  

      locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

      Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
      if(extras !=null)
      {
       double longitudine = extras.getDouble("long");
       double latitudine = extras.getDouble("lat");

       ((GPSLocationListener) locationListener).setLongitudine(longitudine);
       ((GPSLocationListener) locationListener).setLatitudine(latitudine);

       Log.e("longitudine", "* " + ((GPSLocationListener) locationListener).setLongitudine(longitudine));
       Log.e("latitudine", "* " + ((GPSLocationListener) locationListener).setLatitudine(latitudine));
      }

      String provider = null;


      if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
          provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
      } else 
          if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
              provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
          }

      if(provider != null) {
          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 60000, 15, locationListener);
      }

      Criteria crit = new Criteria();
      crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
      best = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 60000, 15, locationListener);

      Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
      locationListener.onLocationChanged(loc);

  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 10000, 1, locationListener);
      Toast.makeText(this, "GPS tracking started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         // Start location updates; 5s/5m
            LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    60000, 15, locationListener);

            Criteria crit = new Criteria();
            crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
            String provider = locManager.getBestProvider(crit, true);
            Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      //locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

      Toast.makeText(this, "GPS tracking stopped", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(
              Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          locManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

  }


  private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
  {
    double longitudine;
    double latitudine;

    public double setLongitudine(double longitudine) {
        return this.longitudine = longitudine;
    }

    public double setLatitudine(double latitudine) {
        return this.latitudine = latitudine ;
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {  
       Toast.makeText(GPSLocatorActivity.this, "Te plimbi",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      if (location != null) {
       Log.e("longitudine", "*2 " + longitudine);
       Log.e("latitudine", "*2 " + latitudine);
          GeoPoint pointStatie = new GeoPoint(
                  (int) (latitudine * 1E6), 
                  (int) (longitudine * 1E6));


        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
            (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

        // afisaza coordonatele
        /*
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
            " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         */     
        mapController.animateTo(point);
        mapController.animateTo(pointStatie);
        mapController.setZoom(13);
        //mapView.invalidate();

        // add marker for people point
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
        mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(pointStatie);

        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

        String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        String addressStatie = ConvertPointToLocation(pointStatie);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), addressStatie, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }

    }

    public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
            getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        try {
          List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
            point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
            point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

          if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            for (int index = 0; 
        index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
              address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
          }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {        
          e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return address;
      }

    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
      private GeoPoint pointToDraw;

      public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
        pointToDraw = point;
      }

      public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
        return pointToDraw;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);           

        // convert point to pixels
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

        // add marker
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.mark_red);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);    
        return true;
      }
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled (String provider) {
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evidently, you will create new point similar to first one

```
GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(
    (int) (location2.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
    (int) (location2.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

then add it to overlay

```
mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point2);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work, displays only the last point

Comment: This can happen if the second point is far from the first one and out of view port. The map is focused at first point. Try lower zoom level.